# Want to show two maps are homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem but so far I cannot do it.

Let $X$ be a connected CW-space such that its homotopy group is 0 except for the fundamental group.

Let $M$ be a closed manifold and $g: M \to X$ be a map such that $g(m_0)=x_0$ , where $m_0$ and $x_0$ are base points of $M$ and $X$ respectively. Suppose we have a map $F: M \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $F(m,0)=g(m)$ and $F(m,1)=g(m)$ for all $m \in M$ and $F(m_0 \times [0,1])=x_0$.

I want to show that $F$ is homotopic to $\bar g$ relative to $M\times\{0,1\}$, where $\bar g: M\times [0,1] \to X$ is a map obtained by composing the projection to $M$ and the map $g$.

I am not sure how to use the condition that the higher homotopy of $X$ is zero.

(Or am I missing some conditions so that this statement is true?)

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I haven't thought about it for very long but it seems like considering the universal cover of $X$ will be a good idea. As the higher homotopy of $X$ is trivial, its universal cover will be contractible by the CW property and Whitehead's theorem.

Comment: Are the homotopies relative to something? Also, the homotopy you are looking for beteen $F$ and $\overline{g}$, is it supposed to be constant $=g$ along 'the boundary'?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Yes. Thank you for pointing this. I edited the question.

Comment: Do you also require the image of $\{m_0\} \times [0,1]$ to be fixed during the homotopy?